# Generating a random numer in Javascript ending in 0

Tags: javascript

using Math.floor(Math.random) to generate a random number between 0-600 but I want the number to end in in a 0. 10, 20, 30 ....550. Ive tried Math.round as well but I keep getting numbers such as 102 or 13 where they should've been 100 or 10.

```
let apple = [
    { x: Math.floor(600 * Math.random()), y: Math.floor(600 * Math.random()) }
];
```

Comment: You can generate numbers between 0 and 60. And then multiply them by 10.

Answer (score -3):

this code in below convert last number to 0
so you can create your number with math.floor and in the last just replace last number with 0

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
console.clear();
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var number1=$("#number1").val();
    number1=number1.toString();
    alert(number1);
    var index=((number1.length)-1);
    number1=number1.replaceAt(index, "0");
    alert(number1);
    
    var number2=$("#number2").val();
    number2=number2.toString();
    index=((number2.length)-1);
    number2=number2.replaceAt(index, "0");
    alert(number2);

var number3=$("#number3").val();
    number3=number3.toString();
    index=((number3.length)-1);
    number3=number3.replaceAt(index, "0");
    alert(number3);
    
    
    //alert("ok");
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="number1" value="5" />
<input id="number2" value="44" />
<input id="number3" value="543" />
<button id="myBtn" >click<bottun>
```